# Is there a way to install an old version of a Windows (Universal) application?

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app

Netflix recently updated their app in the Windows Store and, because they're updating to a new development infrastructure, there are some features missing.  The previous version is much better.  I'd like to wait to update until they get back to feature parity.

How do we install old versions?

Comment: this is not possible. I've asked this MS some time ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot say this with 100% certainty, as I do not use the Netflix app, however I feel the following is correct.  With an internet connected application like Netflix, there is no way to use the older store application.  The app checks in with Netflix, which will force it to stop working until it is upgraded.  Even if you didnt upgrade, more than likely the new streaming and DRM technologies are incompatible with the old app.

Comment: If somebody has a copy of it, it might be as simple as replacing the application folder, but the problem is finding a source for that data. The entire platform really wasn't designed to allow for this though.